# Change button background in ListView and CustomAdapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I am new in this stuff so i hope its not a ridiculous question... 
I have a list view, and all the items including a video, numOfLikes(textview), like and dislike (Buttons).
When I click on the like or dislike button, I try to change the background of the button, but it changes the background of all the like/dislike buttons in the list view.

The same happens when I am trying to enable the dislike button while I am clicking on the like button, it disables all the dislike buttons in the list.

**Code :**

```
public class FeedAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Feed> {

Context context;
ArrayList<Feed> feedsList;
ArrayList<String> listOfItems;
Dialog dialog;

public FeedAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<Feed> feeds) {
    super(context, resource, feeds);
    this.context = context;
    this.feedsList = feeds;
}

public FeedAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Feed> feeds){
    super(context, R.layout.feed_listitem, feeds);
    this.context = context;
    this.feedsList = feeds;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final FeedHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.feed_listitem, parent, false);
        holder = new FeedHolder();

        holder.titleTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_title_textView);
        holder.usernameTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_name_textview);
        holder.likesTextView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_likes_textview);
        holder.likeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_like_button);
        holder.unlikeButton = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_unlike_button);
        holder.video = (VideoView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_post_videoView);
        holder.frameLayout = (FrameLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.feed_placeholder_framelayout);

        holder.frameLayout.setTag(holder.video);
        holder.likeButton.setTag(holder.unlikeButton);
        holder.unlikeButton.setTag(holder.likeButton);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else{
        holder = (FeedHolder) convertView.getTag();
        holder.frameLayout.setTag(holder.video);
        holder.likeButton.setTag(holder.unlikeButton);
        holder.unlikeButton.setTag(holder.likeButton);
    }

    holder.titleTextView.setText(feedsList.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.usernameTextView.setText(feedsList.get(position).getUsername());
    holder.likesTextView.setText(TrendliContract.showNumInNumK(feedsList.get(position).getLikesInLong()));

    holder.titleTextView.setTypeface(TrendliContract.helvetica);
    holder.usernameTextView.setTypeface(TrendliContract.helvetica);
    holder.likesTextView.setTypeface(TrendliContract.helvetica);

    holder.frameLayout.setBackground(feedsList.get(position).getDrawable());
    holder.video.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    holder.video.setMediaController(new MediaController(context));  
    holder.video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(feedsList.get(position).getVideoImageGif()));
    holder.video.setLayoutParams(new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(TrendliContract.screenW,
            TrendliContract.screenW));

    postImageViewOnClickListener(holder);

    holder.likeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Feed f = feedsList.get(position);
            //Button b = ((Button) v.getTag());
            if(f.isLikePressed() == false){
                new TrendliContract.Like().execute(f);
                f.setLikePressed(true);
                int numOfLikes = Integer.parseInt(holder.likesTextView.getText().
                        toString().replace(" ", ""));
                holder.likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(++numOfLikes));
                //v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
                //b.setEnabled(false);
            } else{
                new TrendliContract.UnLike().execute(f);
                f.setLikePressed(false);
                int numOfLikes = Integer.parseInt(holder.likesTextView.getText().
                        toString().replace(" ", ""));
                holder.likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(--numOfLikes));
                //v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.transparent);
                //b.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }

    });

    holder.unlikeButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Feed f = feedsList.get(position);
            //Button b = ((Button) v.getTag());
            if(f.isDislikePressed() == false){
                new TrendliContract.DisLike().execute(f);
                f.setDislikePressed(true);
                int numOfLikes = Integer.parseInt(holder.likesTextView.getText().toString().replace(" ", ""));
                holder.likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(--numOfLikes));
                //v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
                //b.setEnabled(false);
            } else{
                new TrendliContract.UnDisLike().execute(f);
                f.setDislikePressed(false);
                int numOfLikes = Integer.parseInt(holder.likesTextView.getText().toString().replace(" ", ""));
                holder.likesTextView.setText(String.valueOf(++numOfLikes));
                //v.setBackgroundColor(R.color.transparent);
                //b.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });

    convertView.setTag(holder);
    return convertView;
}






private class FeedHolder{
    TextView titleTextView;
    TextView usernameTextView;
    TextView likesTextView;
    Button likeButton;
    Button unlikeButton;
    VideoView video;
    FrameLayout frameLayout;
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must **never** change the properties of `ListView` item's view in the `onClick` event.

The reason is that the `onClick` event get called out of `getView` method in a different time and because of recycling system of `ListView` those affected properties will be applied to recycled views, so you get irrelevant results.

Instead you must store the properties in an array and then in the `getView` method use that array to apply properties to views...

In the `Adapter` class

```
boolean[] buttonState;
```

In the `constructor`:

```
buttonState = new boolean[feeds.size()];
```

In the `onClick`:

```
buttonState[position] = false; // or true...
```

In the `getView`:

```
holder.yourButton.setEnabled(buttonState[position]);
```

Comment: its not applying any changes for setEnabled in getView

Answer (score 1):

As a variant you can create custom button class extends Button and implements View.OnClickListener, then override it's onClick method to set background corresponding with the flag like mPressed. After that you can use this class for yours buttons. Here an example of custom button class:

```
public class CustomButton extends Button implements View.OnClickListener {
    private boolean mPressed = false;
    private static final int mRegularBackID = R.drawable.button_up;
    private static final int mPressedBackID = R.drawable.button_down;

    public CustomButton( Context context ) {
        super( context );
    }
    public CustomButton( Context context, AttributeSet attrs ) {
        super( context, attrs );
    }
    public CustomButton( Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle ) {
        super( context, attrs, defStyle );
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick( View view ) {
        mPressed = !mPressed;
        this.setBackgroundResource( mPressed ? mPressedBackID : mRegularBackID );
    }

}
```

Instead of static drawable IDs with the flag  (as in my example) you can also use drawable state list or constructor with corresponding drawables as additional parameters.

You can use this custom class in XML with full package name like

```
<my.own.project.package.CustomButton... />
```

Answer (score 0):

View passed in `onClick(View v)` it's clicked Button object you can use it to change Button property.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
   Button b = ((Button)v);
   b.setEnabled(false);
}
```

You can setup `background` property of `Button` inside your xml layout. Even you can define drawable xml slector witch will define different background for different states like: pressed, focused, disabled, etc.
First you have to define selector xml and set it as Button background:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/selected" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/selected" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/transparent"/>
</selector>
```

Instead of colors you can use drawable resources (images or shapes). Also you can define different states in this list. First element in selector witch match current satte will be used.

Answer (score 0):

Try --

```
 likeButton.setBackgroundColor(R.color.transparent);
 unlikeButton.setEnabled(false);
```

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors, when you add some explaination to your intension.